# Limitation of Gauss's Law

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, electric-fields, gauss-law, approximations

We can use Gauss's law to find out the electric field $\vec{E}(\vec{r})$ due to an infinite cylinder of charge.

[image]

But if the cylinder is of finite length then it is said that $|\vec{E}(\vec{r})|$ is valid at $\vec{r}$ when $r<< R$.

Why this is so? And how can I prove this condition mathematically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

rodrigo has a good explanation for why this intuitive explanation is useful.

If you wanted to prove it mathematically, you'd have to find the exact field first. Here's an example from Griffiths: If you have a line of charge with linear charge density $\lambda$ on the $x$-axis running from $-L$ to $+L$, the field at some height $z$ above its midpoint is given by
$$
E = \frac 1{4\pi\epsilon_0} \frac{2\lambda L}{z\sqrt{z^2+L^2}}.
$$
If you have dissimilar numbers $a\gg b$, then $$\sqrt{a^2+b^2} = a\sqrt{1+\frac{b^2}{a^2}} = a \left(1 + \frac 12 \frac {b^2}{a^2} + \mathcal O\left(\frac{b^4}{a^4}\right)\right).$$
Very near the line of charge, $z \ll L$, we have 
$$
E = \frac 1{4\pi\epsilon_0} \frac{2\lambda L}{zL} \left(1-\frac12 \frac{z^2}{L^2} +\cdots \right) \approx \frac 1{4\pi\epsilon_0} \frac{2\lambda}{z}
$$
which is the field of an infinite cylinder; very far from the line, $z\gg L$, we have
$$
E = \frac 1{4\pi\epsilon_0} \frac{2\lambda L}{z^2} \left(1-\frac12 \frac{L^2}{z^2} +\cdots \right) \approx \frac 1{4\pi\epsilon_0} \frac{q}{z^2}
$$
which is the field due to a point with charge $q=2\lambda L$.

Answer (score 1):

It is an intuitive approximation. I guess that you could calculate the exact electric field for a finite cylinder and then see that effectively, it is approximately equal to the infinite one when $ r << R$.

But the idea of using Gauss in the first place is not to have to calculate the finite cylinder case explicitly. Why is the approximation valid? Well, think the other way around, why is a long finite cylinder different from an infinite one? Becase there is caps instead of yet more cylinder! But if the caps are far away ($R$ is big) from the point you are doing the calculations, the difference between a cap or a longer cylinder will be negligible.

Note that for this approximation to be valid, you have to be near the cylinder ($r$ is small) so that the charges near the measured point dominates over all the others. If you move away from the cylinder, then it will start to look more and more as a point and less like an infinite-cylinder.

Answer (score 0):

Gauss's law is always valid.

What the trick is is to pick a surface where the crossing value of D is 0 or some constant d.  Then you have d.A (for the non-zero areas) = Q (the embedded charge).

The example of the section of infinite wire works, because the cylinder-ends have D=0, and the round wall has $D=Q/2\pi l.r$, and since we have $Q/l$ as the charge on the wire, it allows us to derive $E$ from $Q/l$ and $r$.

In your case of a short peice of wire, the cylinder model is not an easy calculation because the flux is not orthogonal to the surface, and not uniform, which pretty much defeats the process.

Answer (score -1):

1.it is only applicable for calculating electric field lines through a closed surface.
2.only applicable for symmetrical charge distribution.